# Change file name from lowercase to uppercase. use git config --local core.ignorecase false, but two files in the same name but different case

Tags: git, gitlab

I changed file name from lowercase to uppercase, then I tried to merge.

It was failed, so I add

```
git config --local core.ignorecase false
```

Then it became same name but two files in gitlab (one with uppercase, one with lowercase).

If I clone the project, it will be all lowercase.

I tried to delete the lowercase one in gitlab, but if I pull again, the file will be empty.

Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: What did you do to "delete the lowercase one in gitlab" ? did you click the "edit" link and delete the content of the file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to fix this problem is to use a system in which lowercase and uppercase are distinct.  For instance, if you are stuck with Windows, fire up WSL or use VirtualBox or similar to create a Linux system, clone the repository into this other OS, fix things up, commit, and push new commit.  (You can then shut down the WSL or VirtualBox instance.)

## Long-ish: what's going on

You've misused `core.ignoreCase`: you're lying to Git, and Git got its revenge.

There's a key concept here that's a little tricky, and unfortunately, a lot of Git documentation is unclear and a lot of Git tutorials and introductory materials are not great or even downright *bad*, which can [lead you down the garden path](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lead%20%28someone%29%20down%2Fup%20the%20garden%20path) here.  Here is what you need to know:

- Any given Git repository stores *commits* (and names, such as branch and tag names, that help you and Git *find* the commits, but here we'll concentrate specifically on the commits).
- *Commits* store files—but they do so in a special, weird, exclusive-to-Git format.  Commits don't store directories (folders), only files; each file has a name, and that name consists of any arbitrary byte sequence with only a few constraints: specifically, the name must not start with a (forward) slash and cannot have two adjacent forward slashes, and it cannot contain a NUL byte (a `b'\0'` in Python-style encoding).  Two different byte sequences represent different file names, so `path/to/file` and `path/TO/FILE` are two different files; `path/TO/file` is a *third* different file, and so on.  Note that there are no folder names here: `path/to/file` is a *file* name, that merely happens to contain things that *work like* folder names when you're getting your real work done, rather than poking around with Git.
- To *check out* a commit (with `git checkout` or `git switch`), Git will *extract* the files *from the commit* into a what Git calls a *working tree*.  Here the files will be ordinary files on your ordinary computer so that ordinary programs can do ordinary things with them.
- Git actually builds *new* commits from what Git calls its *index* or *staging area* (or, sometimes, *cache*).  This thing holds files, in the same *format* that Git uses for commits, so the files in the index have long names (`path/to/file`) that *are case-sensitive*, regardless of whether your system is case-sensitive or not.

Hence a Git repository, which stores commits which store files, can contain a commit that has two files that differ only in case, such as `readme.md` and `README.md`.  This is always true: no setting you can set in Git can stop this from being true.

Most *operating systems* and/or *file systems* have constraints on how files can appear.  Not all OSes and file systems are the same here: in particular, Windows, after breaking a long `path/to/file.ext` string into components `path`, `to`, and `file.ext` (and then expressing that as `path\to\file.ext` later!) forbids the `file` part from being named `aux`.  Try to create an `aux` or `aux.h` file for a C or C++ program, or an `aux.py` file for a Python program, and see what happens.  This works fine on Linux and macOS, but not on Windows.<sup>1</sup>

Both Windows and macOS will, by default in most file systems, *retain* the *case* of a newly created file or folder, so that if you make a new file named `README.md`, it's really named `README.md`.  But both systems will, from then on, treat attempts to create or use `readme.md` (in all lowercase) as requests to use the existing `README.md` file.  That is, these *operating systems and/or file systems* **ignore** the case you use in favor of the case of some existing file or folder.

This means that, should you have a commit that has *both* `README.md` *and* `readme.md` in it, *checking out* this commit can only extract *one of these two files*.  Whichever file name Git creates *first* will be the name you will see in your working tree.  Let's say, for concreteness, that Git creates `README.md` first.  The *second* file will simply overwrite the first one, leaving you with just a single file named `README.md`, containing the `readme.md` file's *content*.

What `core.ignoreCase` (which, as a configuration variable, ignores case so that you can set `core.ignorecase` or `core.IGNORECASE` if you like) is for is to *tell Git how the system behaves*.  Changing it won't change how the system behaves!  It's a **de**scriptive setting, not a **pre**scriptive setting.

It's occasionally (though rarely) useful to change the setting temporarily to *trick Git*.  You **should** never have to do this, in an ideal world in which Git is perfect, but that world simply does not (and never will) exist.  So you'll find the occasional StackOverflow answer that has you temporarily change `core.ignoreCase` and do something.  **Be sure to change it back when you're done though** because Git *believes the setting*.  If it's set wrong, Git will misbehave.  The answer that says "change it" is *deliberately lying to Git to get it to misbehave* in a way that turned out to be useful that one time, and maybe will be again, as long as you have the same version of Git and the same version of Windows *or* it still just happens to work that way.

In particular, when you turn `core.ignoreCase` off (set it to `false`), Git believes that the OS *can* hold both uppercase and lowercase variants of some file.  You would typically do this to manipulate Git's *index*.  Running `git add file.ext` will now add the *lowercase* version and running `git add FILE.EXT` will add the uppercase version (and running `git add FiLe.eXt` will add a mixed-up-case third version).  Running `git rm --cached` will let you remove any one particular case version from Git's index, all while believing that case is significant.  Once you're done with this manipulation, you should restore the `core.ignoreCase` setting so that it describes how your system really works.

You can use `git ls-files --stage` (or even without `--stage`, `--stage` just makes the output much more detailed here) to see *what files are in Git's index right now*.  Be aware that this command produces a *full list of every file*, which in a large repository, can be very long, so you might want to use bash-style redirection:

```
$ git ls-files --stage > output.tmp
```

and then use a file-viewer on `output.tmp` and then remove `output.tmp` when you're done, for instance.

---

<sup>1</sup>While macOS avoids some Windows issues, the case-folding thing is still in effect *unless* you make a case-sensitive file system.  It's easy to make a mountable `.dmg` file that holds such a file system, and if you use a Mac, it's a good idea to have one around so that you can deal with Git repositories made on Linux.

Note that macOS has a rather different problem with certain Unicode sequences, which is as insurmountable in macOS as the `aux.h` problem is on Windows.  So you might still want a Linux you can bring up on your Mac.